Python type checking with Pyright -
In the below code, Pyright/Mypy will complain on the line "a.b.doSomeStuff()":
"doSomeStuff" is not a known attribute of "None"
Adding a check that a.b is not None will of course solve this.
But assume there are loads of similar calls and you don't want to clutter the code with these "ifs" - is there some neat way of telling Pyright/Mypy that create_a() will ensure a.b is not None?
from typing import Optional


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")

    def doSomeStuff(self):
        print("hello")

    something: int = 1


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello")

    b: Optional[B] = None


class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")

    def create_a(self) -> A:
        a = A()
        a.b = B()
        return a


class D:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
        c = C()
        a = c.create_a()
        a.b.doSomeStuff()


it might be worth creating another (sub)type where b isn't Optional.

In addition to my proposed answer, it seems (at least from the MWE you gave) that you have classes that could be functions for better readability, in Python not everything needs to be encapsulated in a class

The static type of A.b is B|None; you can't change that in create_a. You need a different class where b is not optional.

This is a very common question. Duplicates: Make mypy to understand, that the attribute is not None, How to create a TypeGuard to ensure value not None in python?. There must be a better dupe somewhere I haven't found yet.

In A it is optional, so it is optional. If you don't want for it to be optional, then return something where it is not optional. Types are static, they don't depend on what the code does. If it is not optional, you have to statically annotate it. For example the code below presents another class A_where_b_is_not_optional where b is not optional.
from typing import Optional

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")

    def doSomeStuff(self):
        print("hello")

    something: int = 1


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello")

    b: Optional[B] = None

class A_where_b_is_not_optional(A):
    b: B


class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")

    def create_a(self) -> A:
        a = A_where_b_is_not_optional()
        a.b = B()
        return a


class D:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
        c = C()
        a = c.create_a()
        a.b.doSomeStuff()

